# AJAX in Django - Clicking an element updates all counters tied to the update script. How can I prevent this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I'm doing a small project, learning how to use AJAX and it turned out to be a little uncomfortable. When I press the like button, the counter increases or decreases in all the elements. For example if I like question 1, in the question 2 and 3 the like counter also changes and uses the same counter as the one in question 1. How can I avoid it?

This is my script:

```
  $(".like-button").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/like/",
    data: {'slug': $(this).attr('name'), 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{csrf_token}}'},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response){
      sl = $(".show-likes");
      sl.html(response.likes_count);
    },
    error: function(rs, r){
      alert(rs.responseText);
    }
  });
});
```

This is my html template:

```
{% for tweet in tweets %}
  <!--Card-->
  <div class="card col">
      <!--Card content-->
      <div class="card-body">
          <!--Title-->
          <h4 class="card-title">{{tweet.title}}</h4>
          <!--Text-->
          <p class="card-text">{{tweet.text}}</p>
        <button
          type="button"
          name="{{tweet.slug}}"
          class="btn btn-primary like-button">Likes
          <span
          class="show-likes">
            {{tweet.total_likes}}
          </span>
        </button>
      </div>
  </div>
  <hr>

{% endfor %}
```

Inside of the like button's code, I have a  for showing "total_likes".

And how could I add a little more real-time updating to this? I'm using Django as the Backend.

Thank you very much for your time and have an excellent day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to descend from the clicked like button (`this` within the handler) to find the likes counter for that button only. Otherwise your `'.show-likes'` query will yield all counters on the page.

```
$(".like-button").click(function(e){
  var $btn = $(this);

  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/like/",
    data: {'slug': $(this).attr('name'), 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{csrf_token}}'},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response){
      var sl = $btn.find(".show-likes");
      sl.html(response.likes_count);
    },
    error: function(rs, r){
      alert(rs.responseText);
    }
  });
});
```

Also, not sure what you mean by adding "more" real-time updating. You might be referring to what's known as an "optimistic update". In this case you would update the likes counter immediately (increment by one), and then call your ajax function. Your handler would remain the same and update with the actual, trusted value from the server once complete. If other users have clicked like during that time, the final value from the server may be higher.

Comment: You could also use the [`context`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) property instead of the extra `$btn` variable: `$.ajax({..., context: $(this), ... }` + `var sl = $(this).find(".show-likes")`

Comment: @Andreas Yes or a lambda function: `success: response => $(this).find('.show-likes').html(response.likes_count)`